# Scriptural age for Srimad Bhagavata Purana

Tags: bhagavata-purana

There are [several opinions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origin_of_the_Bhagavata_Purana#Ludo_Rocher) on when the Srimad Bhagavata Purana originated.

Other than the opinions of the modern scholars, does the Srimad Bhagavatam comment on its time of origin? Any lines from the scripture say about its time of origin either directly or indirectly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Does the Srimad Bhagavatam comment on its time of origin?**

Yes, the somewhat similar questions are clarified in the [Bhagavatam: Chapter 4](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/1/4/):

> Text 3: In what period and at what place was this first begun, and why was this taken up? From where did Kṛṣṇa-dvaipāyana Vyāsa, the great sage, get the inspiration to compile this literature?

After compiling Vedas and Mahabharata, Vyasadeva was not satisfied. On the banks of the river Sarasvatī, Vyasadeva got inspiration from sage Narada to write Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam. So, it's time of origin is after Mahabharata war (at the conjunction time of Dwapara and Kaliyuga).

Answer (score 3):

Srimad Bhagavatam is one of the major 1`8 puranas.
Brhadaranyaka Upanishad 4.5.11:

the yathārdraidhāgner abhyāhitasya prthag DHUM viniścaranty evam va are 'sya Mahato bhūtasya niḥśvasitam etad yad Rig Veda yajurvedaḥ Samaveda' tharvāṅgirasa itihāsaḥ Purana vidyā upaniṣadaḥ ślokāḥ sūtrāṇy anuvyākhyānāni vyākhyānanīṣṭaṃ hutam Asit pāyitam Ayam lokaḥ Paras ca ca ca lokaḥ sarvāṇi Bhutan |
asyaivaitāni sarvāṇi niśvasitāni || BrhUp_4,5.11 ||
.
This sloka confirms that puranads have manifested from the breath of god.
But Sri Vyasadeva just wrote the purana which he learnt from Narada muni, who learned it from
brahma who learned it from Sri Lord Krishna.
He presented it in the form in which Suta Goswami narrated it who learned The Srimad Bhagavatam from his guru Srila Sukadeva Goswami.

Sri RadheKrishna ki Jay